# Docker compose executable file not found in $PATH": unknown

Tags: python, django, docker, docker-compose

but I'm having a problem.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 0
RUN mkdir /code
WORKDIR /code
COPY requirements.txt /code/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . /code/
```

compose.yml :

```
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    volumes:
      - ./docker/data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=sampledb
      - POSTGRES_USER=sampleuser
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=samplesecret
      - POSTGRES_INITDB_ARGS=--encoding=UTF-8

  django:
    build: .
    environment:
      - DJANGO_DEBUG=True
      - DJANGO_DB_HOST=db
      - DJANGO_DB_PORT=5432
      - DJANGO_DB_NAME=sampledb
      - DJANGO_DB_USERNAME=sampleuser
      - DJANGO_DB_PASSWORD=samplesecret
      - DJANGO_SECRET_KEY=dev_secret_key
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    command:
      - python3 manage.py runserver
    volumes:
      - .:/code
```

error :

```
ERROR: for django  Cannot start service django: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:346: starting container process caused "exec: \"python3 manage.py runserver\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown
```

At first, I thought Python Manage was wrong.

But i tried command `ls` , To my surprise, I succeeded.

Then I tried the ls -al command, but it failed.

I think the addition of a command to write space is causing a problem.

how can i fix it ?

Comment: Try running runserver command from your DockerFile as an ENTRYPOINT

Comment: @Kendoka Then, can I take out the command in Compose.yml?

Comment: If you run it as ENTRYPOINT in DockerFile you can take out command in your compose file.

Comment: you ned to remove the COPY . /code/ from your dockerfile since it defined in compose

Answer (score 17, accepted):

When you use list syntax in the `docker-compose.yml` file, each item is taken as a word.  You're running the shell equivalent of

```sh
'python3 manage.py runserver'
```

You can either break this up into separate words yourself

```
command:
  - python3
  - manage.py
  - runserver
```

or have Docker Compose do it for you

```
command: python3 manage.py runserver
```

In general fixed properties of the image like this should be specified in the Dockerfile, not in the `docker-compose.yml`.  Every time you run this image you're going to want to run this same command, and you're going to want to run the code built into the image.  There are two syntaxes, with the same basic difference:

```
# Explicitly write out the words
CMD ["python3", "manage.py", "runserver"]

# Docker wraps in sh -c '...' which splits words for you
CMD python3 manage.py runserver
```

With the code built into the image and a reasonable default command defined there, you can delete the `volumes:` and `command:` from your `docker-compose.yml` file.