# How to open postgres db and see the tables (Django+Postgres+Docker)

Tags: django, postgresql, docker, docker-compose, pgadmin

I start learning docker with Django+PostgreSQL, I did all steps from there https://docs.docker.com/samples/django/

How can I open created database on terminal or pgAdmin to see tables and change them?

I use: Ubuntu 22.04 / Docker Engine 20.10.17 / Docker Compose version v2.6.1 / psycopg2-binary==2.9.3 / Django==4.0.6 / psql (13.7 (Ubuntu 13.7-1.pgdg22.04+1))

my docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3.9"

services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    volumes:
      - ./data/db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
  web:
    build: .
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_NAME=postgres
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
    depends_on:
      - db
```

my settings.py:

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
    'NAME': os.environ.get('POSTGRES_NAME'),
    'USER': os.environ.get('POSTGRES_USER'),
    'PASSWORD': os.environ.get('POSTGRES_PASSWORD'),
    'HOST': 'db',
    'PORT': 5432,
}
}
```

some info if needed, postgres file created are owned by root:

[postgres file 1/2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eBAqL.png)

[postgres file 2/2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ay8Rr.png)

[docker-compose commands](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3y5hg.png)

Thanks for answers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
docker exec -it {your postgres container name} psql -U {your db username} {your db name}
```

or simply

```
docker compose exec {service name} manage.py dbshell
```

Comment: Yep, but nothing: https://imgur.com/a/zRi9Bd0

Comment: when you run those commands what's the exact results? any error message?

Comment: yes, i did and add the screen named by 'docker-compose commands'
1 error mes: Error: No such container: postgres

2 error mes: OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: unable to start container process: exec: "manage.py": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown

Comment: @almanac Let's read throught the error logs. `Error: No such container: db` Based on the screencapture you added, your postgres container name is `django1-db-1`, So the command should be like this:

```
docker exec -it django1-db-1 psql -U postgres postgres
```
(btw sharing logs in text format would be much better than images)
About this(`manage.py executable file not found: $PATH unknown`), you can refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59209889/docker-compose-executable-file-not-found-in-path-unknown .

Comment: [1] First command helped, but when I execute the command, I took this text 'psql (14.4 (Debian 14.4-1.pgdg110+1))', I still don't know why Debian.  Thanks a lot man!

Comment: is that the entire result you got?