# Executable file not found in $PATH unkown

Tags: java, docker, docker-compose

I am currently trying to set-up an instance of Open Trip Planner 2 in docker. I have created two compose files which execute the same docker image, but with different arguments.

However, currently I am having quite a lot of trouble getting the OTP JAR file to execute correctly.

I am getting the following error:
`ERROR: for otp  Cannot start service otp: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: exec: "otp": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown`.

After a quick google search I found the
[following question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59209889/docker-compose-executable-file-not-found-in-path-unknown), but after changing the docker-compose command argument, the error still occurs.

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM openjdk:11
LABEL maintainer="Tristan van Triest <tristantriest@gmail.com>"

ENV OTP_VERSION=2.1.0

ADD https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/opentripplanner/otp/$OTP_VERSION/otp-$OTP_VERSION-shaded.jar /usr/local/share/java/

RUN ln -s otp-$OTP_VERSION-shaded.jar ./otp.jar

COPY . .

EXPOSE 8080

ENTRYPOINT [ "otp" ]
```

My docker-compose file:

```yaml
version: '3.7'

services:
  otp:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: dockerfile
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - 9494:8080
    volumes:
      - ./graphs:/var/otp/graphs
    environment:
      - JAVA_OPTIONS=-Xmx8G
    command:
      [
        '--maxThreads 4',
        '--insecure',
        '--verbose',
      ]
```

The "entrypoint" OTP file:

```bash
#!/bin/sh

exec java $JAVA_OPTIONS -jar otp.jar $@
```

I just simply want to be able to run the OTP Jar with different arguments. Is there an easier way to do this? Or if my current way is "correct", how can I solve the error?

Thanks,
Tristan

Comment: Not your immediate problem, but `$@` only works correctly when quoted as `"$@"`; otherwise it has all the bugs of `$*`.

Comment: Also, you probably want `'--maxThreads', '4'` as two separate words, unless you use quotes or escapes to hold them together at a shell.